# Manual entry of subject in outlook for VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

How can we enter subject name manually in outlook subject for VBS so that, it will be used to fetch some values in a batfile.

Answer (score 0):

Use InputBox VBS function. See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/08/31/how-can-i-prompt-a-user-for-input/